# Azure Notification Hub - Registered IOS devices overwriting each other

Tags: ios, azure, react-native, azure-notificationhub, hub

Got a strange issue with our notification hub on Azure. I'm using Service Bus Explorer to view what devices are registered.

I can only seem to get a max of 2 IOS devices registered at one time. When a new device registers it overwrites one of the existing ones. The 'RegistrationId' stays the same on both devices but the 'PNSHandle' changes as expected.

I've updated the provisioning profile on the Apple Developer portal and also created a new certificate for deployment as I was worried it may be tied to some sort of sandbox certificate/profile.

Any suggestions would be great :)

Thanks

Comment: Just to highlight the difference on installation vs registration: The installation or registration (depending on the API you are using), is tied uniquely to a single device through its Platform Notification Service (PNS) unique ID.
If you have two devices, this means that you will have two different installations/registrations.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response, I ended up passing through the unique ID generated by the 'react-native-device-info' library to an API on my azure gateway. Then dealing with the registration from there. The library 'react-native-azurenotificationhub' I tried using was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Posted the comment as answer. --Just to highlight the difference on installation vs registration: The installation or registration (depending on the API you are using), is tied uniquely to a single device through its Platform Notification Service (PNS) unique ID. If you have two devices, this means that you will have two different installations/registrations.
Thanks for the sharing additional info and update,kurtis_dev